# invoke Grails tag with static body

Tags: grails, tags

If I want to use the [g.link tag](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/link.html) to link the text "foo" to the list action of the book controller, I can do that with:

```
<g:link action='list' controller='book'>foo</g:link>
```

The code above shows the "tag syntax", but how can I do the same thing using the "method call syntax"? I tried the following:

```
g.link(action: 'list', controller: 'book', {'foo'})
```

but it doesn't work. The problem is that I can't figure out how to pass a static piece of text for the `body` parameter. In the example above, I've tried putting the text in a closure, but this didn't work.

Comment: Post your code where you are passing the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is e.g. inside controller, you can use:

```
link( controller:'book', action:'list' ) { 'foo' }
```

It is not necessary to use the 'g' namespace, it is automatically injected.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
g.link ([uri:'/'], {"hello"})
```